# Fortran mode: Moving with M-f or M-b suddenly stopped working

Tags: key-bindings, keymap

I was using `fortran-mode` for some time without problem, but recently the bindings `M-f` and `M-b` stopped working.

It seems that they are not bound to the `forward-word` and `backward-word` moving commands anymore, but instead to some commands defined in a file called **ftnchek.el** (this is what `C-h k` told me about them), which is apparently a "fortran 77 syntax and semantics checker". In this file, I found these:

```
    ; I'm not sure I like these but nobody's complaining.
    (define-key fortran-mode-map "\C-x`" 'ftnchek-next-error)
    (define-key fortran-mode-map "\M-s" 'ftnchek-subprogram)
    (define-key fortran-mode-map "\M-b" 'ftnchek-buffer)
    (define-key fortran-mode-map "\M-p" 'ftnchek-previous-subprogram)
    (define-key fortran-mode-map "\M-n" 'ftnchek-next-subprogram)
    (define-key fortran-mode-map "\M-f" 'ftnchek-first-executable)
    (define-key fortran-mode-map "\M-h" 'ftnchek-what-subprogram)
```

which I think causes the problem.

So I have two questions:

1. Why do you think these keybindings were working just like in `text-mode` for some time and then started to run the above checking functions?
2. What do you think is the best to do to have the classical behavior of `M-f` and `M-b`, while still accessing the above checking functions? If you think I should modify the part of **ftnchek.el** I am displaying above, do you have any suggestions on new keybindings?

(Note: I am not able to tag this question with "fortran-mode")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ftncheck.el` is not part of Emacs, so it's part of *your* config.

If you don't need ftncheck.el then you can just disable it or remove it.
Otherwise, you can just remove those keybindings:

```
(add-hook 'fortran-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            ;; Use default global binding for M-f and M-b.
            (local-set-key "\M-f" nil)
            (local-set-key "\M-b" nil)))
```

Comment: Thank you. How is it that it is part of my config while I hadn't heard of `ftncheck.el` prior to this problem? And one more thing: there is still a problem: I have to manually `M-x fortran-mode` for the effect of the configuration you suggest to take effect. In other words it doesn't seem to work when I open my file with `emacs myfile.f`. Any ideas why?

Comment: It's ftnchek.el and not ftnche**c**k.el, sorry.

Comment: There is no file whose name starts with `ftn` in Emacs itself.  So it has to come from your config (probably packages you installed or something like that).  E.g. maybe because you don't use vanilla Emacs or you use some pre-made config like Prelude or Spacemacs.

Comment: As for why you need to call `M-x fortran-mode` to make it take effect, my best guess is that some part of your config load `ftnchek.el` "lazily", so it takes place after your hook was run the first time, thus overriding the effect of the first run of the hook (but on the second run, the package isn't re-loaded so the hook's effect stick that time around).  Maybe the value of `fortran-mode-hook` could give us some idea what's going on.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all that. The value of `fortran-mode-hook` is the following:`((lambda nil
   (local-set-key "\346" nil)
   (local-set-key "\342" nil))
 ftnchek-mode)

Original value was nil`. By the way, could you please tell me what is the best way to "disable" ftnchek.el?

Comment: No, I can't, because I have no idea how you enabled it (apparently it's not via `fortran-mode-hook` since that one only holds the code I provided).

Comment: If I comment the code you provided (I have put it in my config file), then after restarting Emacs the value of `fortran-mode-hook` is `(ftnchek-mode)`, and it tells me that it is defined in `fortran.el`...

Comment: So, indeed `ftncheck-mode` seems to be the way it' enabled.  Now you have to figure out which code adds it to `fortran-mode-hook`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59165/discussion-between-giuseppe-and-stefan).